Biased random walk with chance of staying in place

A random walk has

probability $x$ of moving $+1$,
a probability $y$ of moving $0$,
and a probability $z$ of moving $-1$.


The PMF for arriving at position $m$ after $n$ steps can be found by summing the trinomial coefficients which satisfy the requisite constraints.

But is there a simpler method for finding these ?.

I have tried searching, but search engines have not been very helpful.



My guess is that trinomial coefficients are the simplest way of both understanding and computing the probability of being at $m$ after $n$ steps. But if you care about other properties, e.g. expecre value / variance / expected distance from zero / expected time to reach some threshold, then there might be shortcuts.

These random walks are called lazy random walks in literature
